# VBA - set default linebreak between two content controls

Tags: vba, ms-word, range, line-breaks, word-contentcontrol

I am trying to get lines between two content controls in VBA for Word.
I want to set default line break between two content controls.
If it is more than two line breaks between I want to delete the others.

When doing my code in a loop, merging of strings into the content control makes multiple line breaks after merging into the content control.

How can I set default two line breaks between two content control?

```
Content control A
- line break
- line break 
Content control B
```

Comment: If you need help with your code, it helps a lot if you include it with your question.

Comment: I have find a solution for this. Sub RemoveLineBreak()

Dim rStart As Range
Dim rEnd As Range


    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ContentC1").Item(1).Range.Select
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

Set rStart = Selection.Range
    
    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ContentC2").Item(1).Range.Select
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
       
Set rEnd = Selection.Range
    
    ActiveDocument.Range(rStart.Start, rEnd.End).Select
    Selection.Delete
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I have find a solution for this.

```
Sub RemoveLineBreak()

Dim rStart As Range
Dim rEnd As Range


    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ContentC1").Item(1).Range.Select
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

Set rStart = Selection.Range

    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ContentC2").Item(1).Range.Select
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

Set rEnd = Selection.Range

    ActiveDocument.Range(rStart.Start, rEnd.End).Select
    Selection.Delete
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak

End Sub
```